# Why do all Cuban hotels have no reviews in booking.com?

Tags: cuba, booking.com, reviews

As the title suggests, why is that?
The hotels are not really new on booking.com, I randomly checked a few hotels and some were listed on booking.com at the end of 2016! we are now in November, 2018, and not a single review for any of the Cuban hotels to be found.

Is it simply the matter of no one ever having visited any of the hotels in Cuba through booking.com and hence no reviews, or am I missing something and there's another interesting reason behind this?

PS. I know about the ban on Cuba and the clash with the US, but booking.com is available for anyone with access to internet, not only to the US.

Comment: Interesting similar example from July https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g147270-i91-k11764314-Booking_com_problems_with_reviews_and_listings-Cuba.html. Could it be to protect identity of American travellers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've received a reply for Booking's Twitter profile on this matter:

> Hi XXXXX, reviews for accommodations in Cuba are no longer displayed in order to comply to a local regulation. If you have more questions, feel free to contact us at any time.

Presumably by "local regulations" they mean the embargo placed on Cuba by the US.

Comment: Tripadvisor.com, a US company, is full of customer reviews for hotels in Havana, Cuba. The idea of a US prohibition isn't persuasive.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the "local regulation" is actually coming from Cuba's side.  Booking.com seems to have some sort of deal with Cuba that allows them the source inventory from Cuba.  Other sites (e.g. Tripadvisor) aren't directly booking or sourcing properties through some Cuban agreement, so they  aren't beholden to that.

Comment: @user3761894 I wouldn't be surprised if Cuba wants to hide reviews since most hotels on the island are awful by Western standards.